# Social Networking Web Class Diagram

Tags: html, class, user-interface, uml, diagram

I am new to UML design, and I would like to know how to get started in developing Class Diagrams for a website, like facebook or twitter. The backend for a class diagram is simple, but for frontend, I have no idea what to do. I know I need classname, attributes, and operations. But I don't know how this would apply to the UI portion of a website. 
I have searched the web, and there is not a lot of material on web page class diagrams. I might have not searched extensively, but I am hoping that someone could help me learn this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is a bit too broad. Alas I'll try a short answer.

As you stated you got the idea behind class diagrams. So you probably have some kind of domain model. A set of classes on client and server side. Now the best approach is to begin with use cases where you describe the behavior of your system and the system goals. Now you create collaborations that realize these use cases. Inside those collaborations you place instances of those classes (in sequence diagrams) from your system domain that take part in the specific use case. Here you start sending messages (using methods of classes) to communicate between the single instances. Add methods/calls as you need to complete the specific design. When done you can create test/start coding the classes.

Of course the above is by fa more complex in practice (you have to deal with different stakeholders) and you find a couple of dependent loops in the process. As said: elaboration of these aspects would us take too far.